# How to set figure inline with section in ACM sig-Alternative template?

Tags: templates, wrapfigure, acm

I have a question of the appearance of an image within my paper.

What I want is the following thing:

```
\subsection{data}
text text text, figure comes below
\begin{figure}
\centering
\epsfig{file=data.eps, height=2.3in, width=3.5in}
\caption{A sample black and white graphic (.eps format)
that needs to span two columns of text.}
\end{figure} 
\section{next section}
above is the figure visible and is positioned within the subsection.
```

Is that possible? Because now the image is positioned on top of the page itself and not inline with the section.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can try `\begin{figure}[!htp]`, but you can't be sure the figure will be at the “best” place. Of course the caption is used just for letting the figure float at the best place from a typographical point of view. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275